# NoClassDefFoundError when working with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, classloader

I am struggling for a couple hours with one problem regarding the initial setup of Hibernate for Eclipse. More precisely I am getting this error and i looked up anywhere for a solution. If anyone could help me with this one i would kindly appreciate it!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.hibernate.test.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What time you are getting this exception?

Comment: Can you share your project structure and the cfg config file location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because the hibernate libraries are not available to Tomcat. In your picture, below the hibernate library set there is an empty set called 'Web App Libraries' - this is the set your hibernate libraries need to be in.

**Right click your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path**, and remove the hibernate set from the build path. Now **import the jars into the WEB-INF/lib folder**. **Refresh your project** and now you should see them listed in the 'Web App Libraries' set (i appreciate this is somewhat annoying that you have to import them into your code base - someone else might know a better way to do this that doesn't involve copying the jars in)

Comment: How do I import the jars into the web-inf/lib folder ?

Answer (score 0):

there is problem your maven dependency. if you are using hibernate annotations, you should add [hibernate-annotations jar](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#setup-requirements)

Comment: I have already included to my project hibernate-annotations-3.5.0-final.jar but still nothing

Comment: Are you using jpa?

Comment: you should add persistence-api and hibernate-core dependencies to maven

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven , then there is some diffrence in versions of hibernate jars ,

Please clean all jars from maven directory and then again let maven download the jars .

I hope this solves your problem .